# If our universe is a "baby universe"

Tags: black-holes, multiverse

There are several theories that claim that our universe is simply a black hole in a "parent" universe:

- Stephen Hawking wrote a book called Black Holes and Baby Universes. Here he talks about black holes "exploding". Due to time dilation, we only see Hawking radiation, and it will take a very long time for a black hole to "explode" as seen from an outside observer. For that reason, we say that the black hole is evaporating. For an inside observer, the explosion would not be time dilated and the explosion could, I believe, resemble cosmic inflation.
- Another theory a few years back says that our universe is simply a 3D surface on a 4D black hole in a "super universe". http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1487

Both these ideas lead me to think that, if there is some merit to this; how would it look for our universe, if something falls into our "parent 4D super-universe"?

It seems to imply that "more mass" can be added to our universe?

Comment: The evaporation of a black hole produces almost entirely very low energy photon states, which will essentially never interact, again. One has to have an entirely different theory on the level of the standard model to make any sense of a naive black hole as baby universe model.

Comment: *"Another theory a few years back says that our universe is simply a 3D surface on a 4D black hole in a "super universe"."*...our universe is already 4D.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I did not claim our universe was 3D, but the theory says 3D *surface* on a 4D sphere. http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1487